# SharePoint 2013, DataTables return [object Object] from LookUp Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, datatable

I'm trying to return value from a LookUp value to my dataTables.  The only thing that returns is [object Object].

Here is an image of my List and result:
[image]

I searched that I should add $expand in my URL line however that did not work.  Any suggestions?
As you can I see I am having issues with my HyperLink column as well but I think I saw a solution on StackExchange so I'll look at that first.

Here is my code:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            GetItems();
        });
        
        function GetItems(){
            //var siteUrl=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            var siteUrl="https://whatever.com";
            var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('datatabletest')/items?$select=Title,HyperLink,LookUp/Title&$expand=LookUp/Title";
            $.ajax({
            url:oDataUrl,
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            headers:{
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            
            success:OnSucces,
            error:OnFailure
            });
        }
        
        function OnSucces(data){
            try{
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    "aaData":data.d.results,
                    "aoColumns":[
                    {"mData":"Title"},
                    {"mData":"HyperLink"},
                    {"mData":"LookUp"}
                    ]
                });
            }
            catch(e){
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }
        
        function OnFailure(data, errMessage){
            alert("Error: " + errMessage);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  Changed:

```
{"mData":"LookUp"}
```

to

```
{"mData":"LookUp.Title"}
```

Comment: Similarly, you can change `HyperLink` to `HyperLink.Url`.